# Pyngrok ngrok ERR_NGROK_3200

Tags: python, server, ngrok, pyngrok

I run my code AS ususal

`

```
from pyngrok import ngrok


ngrok.set_auth_token("token")
# Then call the pyngrok method throwing the error, for example
url = ngrok.connect(80).public_url
print(url)
```

and get

ERR_NGROK_3200

[image: ERR_NGROK_3200]

I use default logging documentation

HERE ARE THE LOGS :https://pastebin.com/TfyfDqV8

My first post :)

i tried using this in Kali got same result idk what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

This means your ngrok agent has stopped. So just start a new agent using this guide
https://ngrok.com/docs/errors/err_ngrok_3200

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple attempts and seems I was able to make it working. below are the steps you may require to perform

You need to register with a different domain name first with below command, and try to `get\post` it using `postman` or `insomania` multiple times along with your local host.

```
ngrok http --domain=new-domain-to-fix-error.com 8080
```

After this, re-run above command with original domain., e.g.

`ngrok http --domain=original-domain-name.com 8080`.
It worked in my case. Hope it gonna work in your's too.

Thanks!